# Where has Angular's virtual ngFor gone?

Tags: angular, angular-material

A while ago now, I remember reading about Angular adding a **virtual** `ngFor`, but I can't quite remember what it was called.

I am now at a stage where I need a virtual scroll list, but looking for this, I am not sure where to find it.

Was this added as part of Angular? (I am using Angular 8/9).

I thought it was called something like `ngVFor` but searching for this I just find [this](https://github.com/anagram4wander/ng-vfor-lib) and trying to run `npm install ng-vfor-lib` it is just not found.

Also [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) I find `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` as part of Angular material, but was hoping to just be able to install a single component, ie not all of Angular material which I am otherwise not using here, as I my app is built within Ionic.

So, to sum up my question is "Is there a standalone Angular `ngVFor`, or is it is "official" component now the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` meaning I need to install all of Angular Material?

Comment: You don't need to install the whole Material package, just `@angular/cdk`

Comment: AFAIK, Angular does not natively support a virtual `ngFor` directive. You may need to install `@angular/cdk`.

Comment: Ok, the ngVFor I saw once must have been some third party component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no official component. You can use `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` which is part of Angular CDK, and you can install Angular CDK without Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics

> In case you just want to install the @angular/cdk, there are also schematics for the Component Dev Kit:
>   `ng add @angular/cdk`

You can also use some components of Angular Material, the whole lib will not be included in your app bundle, only modules used in your app, except for the css.

Comment: OK thanks for that, seems to be the consensus. Now to get that working with my custom component that has an expander (ie variable height which the Ionic virtual scroll did not seem to handle)...

Answer (score 2):

This is the official documentation for what I believe you are looking for:
[Virtual scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Sen, yes I did see that. Cheers